# Hyundai i30 (2014) leaves light on when switched off

Tags: electrical, hyundai, i30-wagon

All the cars I've owned from Kia or Hyundai shut all lights when I left the car. This however leaves all lights as they were while driving.

Can it be rewired to shut all lights when I leave the car?

Comment: Have you looked through the owners manual? There’s likely a procedure to do this.